# PHP - declaring each variable before insert / update or placing each variable in the insert / update in quotes?

Tags: php, insert-update, variable-declaration

I have included error_reporting(E_ALL) in my system. I want to write a better  code.
I am wondering between this two options.

Should I declare absolutely all variables before insert/update (I have a lot of it)?

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
...
$insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table_name (name, ...) VALUES (?, ...)');
$insert->execute(array($name, ...));
```

Or I can quote each variable in the insert/update.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
...
$insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table_name (name, ...) VALUES (?, ...)');
$insert->execute(array("$name", ...));
```

With the second option of course I receive a notice for undeclared variable but I save the load for the ternary check (I add quotes in the insert/update for each variable but this is smaller load compared with the ternary check). With this quotes if the variable is undeclared I insert empty string.
After setting the variables I just insert/update, I don't use it for anything else.

I guess the first option is better but a bit slower.
I just want an additional opinion.

Comment: ternary check does not impose a significant performance penalty, its always good to initialize variables. you can always set a default value and overwrite if the POST variable is set.

Comment: If your id has to be filled, check first your database scheme you should not end with an empty value in your tuple.

Comment: I am voting to leave open, because user is asking how to get rid of errors with error_reporting(E_ALL) on.

Answer (score 0):

**Why send an aditional query when we don't need?**

actually when you haven't `$_POST['s_id']` you don't need to send query, so you can like this, and you'll never receive a notice message, and your queries will optimizied.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['s_id'])) { //instead of $s_id = isset($_POST['s_id']) ? $_POST['s_id'] : '';
// your query code here 
}
```

Comment: The ternary check can be usefull to write less code, if you need to convert html entities for example.

Comment: Agreed with you @LaurentWartel. With ternary we can't put in condition +1 actions.

Comment: When I havne't $_POST['name/s_id'] I still need to send the query. I have a lot of other variables in the query.